# How would I insert image source into text area onclick in react

Tags: javascript, html, image, reactjs

So I have an image object that looks like:

```
[{
  image_src: 'some/src',
  name: 'some name'
},{ ... }]
```

and this lives in `this.state.images`, I would like to say onClick on this image, get the name property from the image tag, search the array of images for an object with the same name and then in the text area, at the cursor position, add that image as markdown: `![name](image_src)`

I have the images displaying as:

```
<img src={img.image_src} onClick={this.addImageToTextArea.bind(this)} data-name={img.name} />
```

And I have the function: `addImageToTextArea(){  }` But I am not sure what to do next.

**Help?**

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to search the image in the array, you can pass it directly to `addImageToTextArea()`.

```
{this.state.images.map((image) =>
   <img className="image" src={image.image_src}
    onClick={this.addImageToTextArea.bind(this,image)} data-name={image.name} />)}
```

or

```
<img className="image"
  src={image.image_src} onClick={() => this.addImageToTextArea(image)}/>
```

Then, you can append the markdown to the textarea with something like this

```
addImageToTextArea(img){
     let stringImage = `![${img.name}](${img.image_src})`;
     let {textArea} = this.refs;
     let value = textArea.value;
     let position = textArea.selectionStart;
     textArea.value = `${value.substr(0,position)}${stringImage}${value.substr(position)}`;
}
```

This method is using a ref to the textarea, dont forget to add it.

```
<textarea ref="textArea"/>
```

[full working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/658/)

Comment: The one small issue with this, is that it doesn't trigger an onChange event for the textarea